# How to preserve additional keys when using "SELECT DISTINCT"?

Tags: postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-8.4

I'm looking to preserve the `sid`, and `cid` pairs that link my tables when using `SELECT DISTINCT` in my query. `signature`, `ip_src`, and `ip_dst` is what makes it distinct. I just want the output to also include the corresponding `sid` and `cid` pairs.

QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT signature, ip_src, ip_dst FROM
     (SELECT *
          FROM event
          INNER  JOIN sensor ON (sensor.sid = event.sid)
          INNER  JOIN iphdr ON (iphdr.cid = event.cid) AND (iphdr.sid = event.sid)
          WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
as d_dup;
```

OUTPUT:

```
 signature |   ip_src   |   ip_dst   
-----------+------------+------------
     29177 | 3244829114 | 2887777034
     29177 | 2960340989 | 2887777034
     29179 | 2887777893 | 2887777556
     29178 | 1208608738 | 2887777034
     29178 | 1211607091 | 2887777034
     29177 |  776526845 | 2887777034
     29177 | 1332731268 | 2887777034
(7 rows)
```

SUB QUERY:

```
SELECT *
          FROM event
          INNER  JOIN sensor ON (sensor.sid = event.sid)
          INNER  JOIN iphdr ON (iphdr.cid = event.cid) AND (iphdr.sid = event.sid)
          WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

OUTPUT:

```
 sid |  cid  | signature |        timestamp        | sid |      hostname       | interface | filter | detail | encoding | last_cid | sid |  cid  |   ip_src   |   ip_dst   | ip_ver | ip_hlen | ip_tos | ip_len | ip_id | ip_flags | ip_off | ip_ttl | ip_proto | ip_csum 
-----+-------+-----------+-------------------------+-----+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+----------+-----+-------+------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+--------+-------+----------+--------+--------+----------+---------
   3 | 13123 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 20:53:14.656 |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13123 | 3244829114 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |    344 | 19301 |        0 |      0 |    122 |        6 |    8686
   3 | 13122 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 20:53:14.43  |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13122 | 3244829114 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |     69 | 19071 |        0 |      0 |    122 |        6 |    9191
   3 | 13121 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 18:45:13.461 |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13121 | 3244829114 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |    366 | 25850 |        0 |      0 |    122 |        6 |    2115
   3 | 13120 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 18:45:13.23  |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13120 | 3244829114 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |     69 | 25612 |        0 |      0 |    122 |        6 |    2650
   3 | 13119 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 18:45:01.887 |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13119 | 3244829114 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |    352 | 13697 |        0 |      0 |    122 |        6 |   14282
   3 | 13118 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 18:45:01.681 |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13118 | 3244829114 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |     69 | 13464 |        0 |      0 |    122 |        6 |   14798
   4 |    51 |     29179 | 2014-11-15 18:44:02.06  |   4 | VS-101-Z1:dna2:dna3 | dna2:dna3 |        |      1 |        0 |       51 |   4 |    51 | 2887777893 | 2887777556 |      4 |       5 |      0 |     80 | 18830 |        0 |      0 |     63 |       17 |   40533
   3 | 13117 |     29177 | 2014-11-15 18:41:46.418 |   3 | VS-101-Z0:dna0:dna1 | dna0:dna1 |        |      1 |        0 |    12888 |   3 | 13117 | 1332731268 | 2887777034 |      4 |       5 |      0 |    261 | 15393 |        0 |      0 |    119 |        6 |   62131
...
(30 rows)
```

How do I keep the `sid`, and `cid` when using `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: I'm not sure have undestood your question, perhaps by adding them  `select distinct cid,sid, signature, ip_src, ip_dst` ?

Comment: The origin of `signature`, `ip_src`, `ip_dst` does not become evident from your query. You should at least table-qualify columns to clarify if you don't provide table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         row_number() over (partition by signature, ip_src, ip_dst order by timestamp desc) as rn
  FROM event
     JOIN sensor ON sensor.sid = event.sid
     JOIN iphdr ON iphdr.cid = event.cid AND iphdr.sid = event.sid
  WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - interval '1' day
) as d_dup
where rn = 1
order by timestamp desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is shorter and probably faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (signature, ip_src, ip_dst)
       signature, ip_src, ip_dst, sid, cid
FROM   event  e
JOIN   sensor s USING (sid)
JOIN   iphdr  i USING (cid, sid)
WHERE  timestamp >= NOW() - '1 day'::interval
ORDER  BY signature, ip_src, ip_dst, timestamp DESC;
```

Assuming you want the *latest* row (greatest `timestamp`) from each set of dupes.
Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.sid, e.cid, ip_src, ip_dst
FROM event e
INNER  JOIN sensor s ON (s.sid = e.sid)
INNER  JOIN iphdr i ON (i.cid = e.cid) AND (i.sid = e.sid)
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL;
```

If you want the combination of (`signature, ip_src, ip_dst`) to be unique in the result (one row for each combination) then you can try something like this:

```
SELECT max(e.cid), max(e.sid), signature, ip_src, ip_dst
FROM event e
INNER  JOIN sensor s ON (s.sid = e.sid)
INNER  JOIN iphdr i ON (i.cid = e.cid) AND (i.sid = e.sid)
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
GROUP BY signature, ip_src, ip_dst;
```

But it will give max `cid` and `sid` for each combination

Comment: This did not work. These keys make it distinct. `signature` `ip_src` `ip_dst`. I think adding `event.sid` and `event.cid` thows off the distinction.

Comment: @insecure-IT So you want the combination of (signature, ip_src, ip_dst) to be unique? (it doesn't clear from your question)

Comment: Yes sorry, I thought it was. I just want the output to also include the corresponding `sid` and `cid` pairs.

Comment: @insecure-IT For the unique combination of (signature1, ip_src1, ip_dst1) you have 3 different cids: 1, 2 and 3. Which cid should be in the result?

Comment: @insecure-IT I've updated my answer. the problem is that if you have different values of cid/sid for the same combination of (signature, ip_src, ip_dst) and you want to show only unique combinations you need to choose only one (aggregate) pair of values cid/sid.

Comment: The `sid` and `cid` can come from event (first two), they just can not be use to be distinct.

Comment: @insecure-IT I think you'd better add the desired output. It's not clear what you do you need.